# Opening an image in a web view on clicking an image on another web view?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ipad, webview

I am developing an iPhone app in which there are big tables to show on web view. I am planning to give a small image at the place of actual table and when the user will click on that, the actual image will open in another webView. I am looking for right direction. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the UIWebViewDelegate protocol method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` for your first webview containing your small images.

When a user clicks your image you need to intercept this event and decide what and how to do.

The [shouldStartLoadWithRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW6) method is called when some kind of interaction is triggered in you webview, such as a link being clicked. Refer to the [UIWebView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW22) for more detail. The shouldStartLoadWithRequest has to return a BOOL to indicate the webview that it should proceed with the action the user performed(return YES) or not(return NO).

Now that you know that a link has been clicked you have to make sure, that it has been an image. This is done by evaluate the url passed back by the request parameter. I've made up a method clickedOnImageWithUrl in the example, which will return YES if an image has been clicked. However, I don't know what your small images embedded in a link look like I cannot provide any more detail on that method. If it returns YES you can show your new webView.

Then the code could look like this to intercept a clicked link:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)aRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        // check if user clicked on your image...clickedOnImageWithUrl is made up
        if([self clickedOnImageWithUrl:[aRequest url]]) {

             // push new webview with image ...

             return NO;
        }            
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify more...pls? Means how I can push new webview with this url?

Comment: @Nick Yes I am aware of the delegate method.But my situation is somewhat different.I have a view containing only a webView.I am creating objects of this view and adding them in a scroll view which is on a different view controller.I am loading each object of my webView with different content.And they are now scrollable.My icon images are in these webpages and when user will click that image I want to show that image in a different view .How can I do that?Thanks for the help you gave till now....

Comment: I am not sure if you really understood what the delegate method does for you. When you've got a webview with clickable images you need to intercept the click, then decide what to show. This has to be done in objective-c and the time you know that you need to show another webview, you can present a new viewcontroller as modal.

Comment: @Nick:Yes I tried the same but the modal viewcontroller gets loaded as a subview of scroll because my webview is added as a subview in a scroll view view and I don't want that

Comment: You can use any view to present a view as modal, vor example a root view controller may do this for you. Anyway, I am not sure what your setup is. I think you should describe it in more detail in your question, a screenshot would help even more.

Comment: @Yogi glad to hear that, so how did you finally do it?

Comment: @Nick: I used [self.view.superview.superview addSubview:table.view] where table.view is the view on which original image is to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

@Yogi: Why do you want to have a table view on top of a UIWebView when you are going to display the image in another webView. I guess just one WebView would be sufficient. By the way you can implement what you want by having a dictionary for the details of the image or perhaps even an array which contains the url for the images. And in the UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can pass the url of the image using the indexpath to the webview which can open the url to view the image.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Get the url for the image here
NSUrlRequest *urlRequest = [NSUrlRequest requestWithURL:urImageUrl];
[urWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Comment: oh,I don't have any table view.The images which I want to show are of tables.So no table view at all.....